# C# code generator

Tags: c#, code-generation

Can someone recommend a simple c# code generator. I just looking something with methods like:

```
GenClass = CreateNewClass(AccessModifier,Name......)

GenClass.Add(new Method(AccessModifier,RetType,Name....){code=@"....."}

GenClass.Add(new Property(AccessModifier,Type, Name....)
```

...........
etc

and after creating all classes\methods and other members we call Code Generation function(where we can specific some parametrs)

Is there such opensource code generator?

Comment: This is something recently written and it's also in nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsCodeGenerator/   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   . It's open source and can be found on github:
https://github.com/borisdj/CsCodeGenerator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [Using CodeDOM to generate CSharp (C#) and VB code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/thottams/using-codedom-to-generate-csharp-c-and-vb-code).

Comment: CodeDOM is too weighty and difficult to study. I am looking something more easy and light

Comment: @Neir0: It's about as easy as it gets, I'm baffled as to what you're looking for if you call this one too difficult.

Comment: If you want the kind of slightly lighter syntax that your question puts forward, I'd suggest writing some very simple extension methods on top of the raw CodeDOM. It's very easy to create a nice fluent API using this technique.

Comment: @280Z28 I'm baffled that you think CodeDOM is the simplest form of code-generation, or even built-in Visual Studio code-generation like T4 templating.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to have a look [csscript](http://www.csscript.net/) that relies on CodeDOM.

It allows you to write things like:

```
var PrintSum = CSScript.LoadMethod(
        @"public static void PrintSum(int a, int b)
          {
              Console.WriteLine((a+b));
          }")
          .GetStaticMethod();
PrintSum(1, 2);
```

Be sure to read the doc, it's pretty detailed and you'll find you can do a lot more than what I just copied before.

Comment: Thanks. But this tool doesn't help to generate code

Answer (score 7):

[T4 or Text Template Transformation Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) might be worth looking into.

Another option is to create your own simple generator, which contains functionality more suited for your situation than the CodeDOM. In a recent code generation project that's what I did, however I have encapsulated the code generation to make it possible to later transition to CodeDOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to generate a class given some arbitray string containing C# code, you need a C# compiler. At the moment the .Net framework does not ship with a compiler that you can pass snippets of C# to and get compiled code back. If you have more specific needs, you should specify exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: @Gabe: why isn't there a compiler within the framework? Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

Comment: I am writing tool which help me automatize typical every day tasks.

Comment: @Oliver I think that compiler is not a part of framework. it's external program (csc.exe) instead c# compiler in mono for example.

Comment: As Neir0 said, all it does is call csc and give you an assembly back. If that's what you're looking for, that's fine. It doesn't seem to be what question was asking. I assumed the question was asking for something like DynamicQuery only accepting full C# syntax.

Comment: This answer isn't really true, as the CodeDOM is part of the framework (except on Silverlight) and allows you to explicitly create snippets and compile them to assemblies which you can then dynamically load either off disk or directly from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly searching for an opensource code generator I suggest [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/). Another, template based approach (which is not what you are looking for since want "GenClass.Add...." syntax rather than templates) would be [Codesmith Tools](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) it's really powerful but closed source.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my open source generator http://code.google.com/p/magicapps/