# Do C# libraries exist to generate source files?

Tags: c#, code-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# code generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536031/c-code-generator)

For example, what I would like to do is something like:

```
Sourcefile sf = new SourceFile("Dog.cs");
sf.add(new Class("Dog"));
sf.Write();
```

and get some text file like:

```
public class Dog()
{
}
```

I can do this myself, but wanted to check around to see if it already existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace is for.

Start reading @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx).

Here's a Hello World [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelpob/archive/2004/01/21/61411.aspx).

You might want to [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) into `System.CodeDom` as well.

Here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) on MSDN.

Use the one that better suits your code generation needs.

PS. If you want to generate code at design time you might want to use T4 templates.

Comment: I though System.Reflection.Emit was about producing MSIL assemblies.  Does it also do source?  I don't see any documentation to suggest this.

Comment: Then CodeDom would be better for you